# Seralization issue in WebApi 2.0

Tags: c#, rest, json.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a REST API using EF 6.0 Code First, AutoMapper and WebApi 2.0.

I am struggling with serializing the data, or to be more specific; selecting what should be serialized when responding to a request.

Lets say i am creating a app for a a football league that has the following classes:

```
public class Player
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; } // example
}

public class Team
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Players { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FootballGame> Games { get; set; }
}

public class FootballGame
{
    public Team Team1 { get; set; }
    public Team Team2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I have a API Controller named PlayersController, and a normal Get method url/api/players/id which should return that player.

However, due to LazyLoading, serialization and many-to-many relations I get every object related to that player returned:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Jon Jones",
  "Teams": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Liverpool",
      "Players": [
        {
          "$id": "3",
          "Id": 2,
          "Name": "James White",
          "Teams": [
            {
              "$ref": "2"
            },
            {
              "$id": "4",
              "Id": 2,
              "Name": "Man Utd",
              "Players": [
                {
                  "$ref": "3"
                },
                {
                  "$id": "5",
                  "Id": 3,
                  "Name": "John Snow",
                  "Teams": [
                    {
                      "$ref": "2"
                    },
                    {
                      "$ref": "4"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$ref": "1"
                }
              ],
              "Games": [
                {
                  "$id": "6",
                  "Id": 1,
                  "Team1": {
                    "$ref": "2"
                  },
                  "Team2": {
                    "$ref": "4"
                  },
                  "DateTime": "2014-08-18T23:20:01.7797942+02:00"
                },
                {
                  "$id": "7",
                  "Id": 2,
                  "Team1": {
                    "$id": "8",
                    "Id": 3,
                    "Name": "Man City",
                    "Players": [
                      {
                        "$ref": "1"
                      },
                      {
                        "$ref": "3"
                      },
                      {
                        "$id": "9",
                        "Id": 4,
                        "Name": "Elton John",
                        "Teams": [
                          {
                            "$ref": "2"
                          },
                          {
                            "$ref": "8"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ],
                    "Games": [
                      {
                        "$ref": "7"
                      },
                      {
                        "$id": "10",
                        "Id": 5,
                        "Team1": {
                          "$ref": "2"
                        },
                        "Team2": {
                          "$ref": "8"
                        },
                        "DateTime": "2014-08-18T23:20:01.7807943+02:00"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "Team2": {
                    "$ref": "4"
                  },
                  "DateTime": "2014-08-18T23:20:01.7807943+02:00"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$ref": "8"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$ref": "5"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "9"
        }
      ],
      "Games": [
        {
          "$ref": "6"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "10"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$ref": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i in a easy way choose to only return the player, and for the teams, rather return the url where the team can data can be obtained, something like:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Jon Jones",
  "Teams": "http://url/api/player/1/teams/"
}
```

Edit:
By disabeling lazyloading as suggested, i just get:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Jon Jones",
  "Teams": []
}
```

If thats the way to go, is there a "best practice" to add the uri to get the Teams in there?

Comment: Please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333143/asp-net-web-api-response-looping-data/25333375#25333375

Answer (score 1):

You should disable lazy loading when building webservices - it's good to force yourself to be explicit about what data is being fetched.  The alternative is to drop [JsonIgnore] attributes on properties of your classes that you don't want the serializer to look at.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Levy suggested, you should disable lazy loading.  Or, you should define DTO's (data transfer objects) in addition to your entities.  These are just plain objects that are not part of entity framework.  Their purpose is to let you define an external API that can look different from your database.  So, then you would query your entities and write some code to map the content of the your POCOs over to your DTOs.

If you are doing something really simple, this can look like overkill (because your DTOs might look exactly like your entity framework object.

For anything non-trivial, though, it can be useful to decouple your database design from the topology of your API.